# How to show a trigger only when pointing to it directly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a transparent cube trigger and I placed it in front of closed doors, so whenever the player walks near the door a message appears saying "this door is locked".
[image]

However, I want the message to be gone whenever the player is Not pointing to the door. currently, it shows even when I turn around, the player needs to walk away from the door to make the message disappear.

[image: Still showing even if I'm not looking at the door.]

Here is my code:

```
public class DoorsTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public GameObject partNameText;
 

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
          
            partNameText.SetActive(true);
          
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            partNameText.SetActive(false);
           
        }
    }  
}
```

How can I modify it to achieve my goal?

Comment: Raycast to see what’s in front of you rather than a trigger perhaps

Comment: You can use Vector3.angle for this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html

Comment: but how would apply it to a certain object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using Vector3.Angle() to get the direction the player is facing relative to that trigger.

```
public class DoorsTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public GameObject partNameText;


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
   
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //Assuming 'other' is the top level gameobject of the player,
            //  or a child of the player and facing the same direction
            Vector3 dir = (this.transform.position - other.gameObject.transform.position);

            //Angle will be how far to the left OR right you can look before it doesn't register
            float angle = 40f;

            if (Vector3.Angle(other.gameObject.transform.forward, dir) < angle) {
                partNameText.SetActive(true);
            }          
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        //Make sure the text is actually showing before trying to disable it again
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && partNameText.activeSelf)
        {
            partNameText.SetActive(false);
       
        }
    }  
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your trigger mostly as is, and do a ray cast from the player to see if they are looking at the door.

```
    //Put this snippet in a function and call it inside the player's Update() loop
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        //Tag the gameObject the trigger is on with "Door"
        if(hit.collider.isTrigger && hit.collider.CompareTag("Door"))
        {
             //Here is where you would call a function on the door trigger to activate the text. 
             // Or better would be to just have that code be on the player.
             // That way you can avoid unnecessary calls to another gameObject just for a UI element!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want to use your first snippet. should I keep the cube trigger in front of the door? and how would I refer to the door using "other"? I tried it but the message doesn't show ;/

Comment: I used the second way, I added this to my player script:   if (hit.collider.isTrigger && hit.collider.CompareTag("Door"))
        {
         
            partNameText.SetActive(true);
          
        }
        else
        {
            partNameText.SetActive(false);
        }
it kidda worked but not completely. when I look at the door and go backwards while still pointing to it, the text stays even if I go far.

Comment: but works when I look right at the door the text shows, when I turn around, it disappears. but the issue is when I go backward it stays!

Comment: You can define the max distance of a Raycast. That will fix your issue of seeing the message from far away. Here is the doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

So it would be Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5f)    for example